# Communication between flash files

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

How can I make something like this: http://www.litespell.com/altinorumcek/banner/etkilesimli/etkilesimli_craxla.html
One flash triggers the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that this might be acheived, but the lack of any supporting Javascript indicates to me that is was performed using [LocalConnection](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html). An AS1/2 version also exists... docs are [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/00001792.html)

Comment: Thank you. I also found an example here: http://www.webwasp.co.uk/tutorials/b21-communication/index.php